# Can you submit two different abstracts about the same data to two different conferences?

Tags: conference, abstract

We were working as a team to gather some data in the medical field and our research was concluded in the summer. I was the only member of the team that was interested in presenting the data so I contacted our senior who supervised the whole research about doing so. He sent me the data and I began writing my abstract for a conference next year. He then told me that he has already sent an abstract to a conference this year for the same data and it has been accepted for oral presentation. Our abstracts are obviously not the same and I am submitting to a different conference entirely but we are using the same data and trying to answer the same question. I am aware that it is forbidden to present data that has been published or presented before as I have submitted abstracts in the past and I have seen it in the rules section. However for the conference I want to send my abstract to, they don't mention anywhere that the results cannot have been published previously. I don't want to do something that is against the rules as I understand these conferences rely on publishing novel data. But its a conference on a totally different topic, a completely different abstract and they do not mention that the data cant have been published before. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Honestly, without knowing the precise details of your field, the differences in your abstracts, and the norms of your field, we really can't answer this for you. Why not ask your senior?

Comment: Most of the time you are definitely NOT supposed to do this but the rules are far more lax. A slight change of title and abstract and you’re off to the next one

Answer (score 2):

In most experimental fields (to which I would definitely slot medicine), it's rather common to present results more than once at conferences.  The obvious reasons for doing this are that different conferences hit different audiences.  Also, that the researcher may be going to the conference to hear other talks, or even enjoy some travel (do not bind the mouths of the oxen!), not ONLY to publish his/her results.

Also I strongly advise to publish your results in a "real journal", widely circulated, not a conference proceedings, only.  [In most fields, CS/Math excluded.]  The conference(s) may have some boilerplate about "original research" or "peer reviewed conference proceedings" (the latter often a very poorly distributed set of volumes).

You have to learn to play the game with that sort of thing (conference proceedings in experimental fields).  Your interests AND the interests of the field are much better served by eventually publishing in JAMA or some lesser but similar "real journal".  Give the conference enough so that it looks good, but not your whole case.  Maybe enough of the problem to flash the motivation (is of interest) and then a subsection of the results.  This is probably enough so that you can still publish the entire study in a real article (or set of them), in real, well-circulated and well-reviewed magazines.  Of course, cite the earlier conference proceedings (gives you as self cite also...woot!), so that you are not covering up doing the earlier publication.  But don't feel bashful about repeating the content from the earlier, page-limited conference proceedings, within your longer "real articles".

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix up publishing in a journal to everybody and presenting results on a conference to a limited audience, you have to spread your results on conferences as far as possible. That's in your and the public interest. And on conferences you might easily get more interdisciplinary attention from other scientific branches than in a very specific field-oriented journal.

I have the impression in branches like CS and physics this is also very differently handled, while in CS conference publications are the status quo, for physiscs, medicine, biology, chemistry this is not so common at all and most important results go through a normal journal review process. Conference papers are often updates or slight variations of results published in a journal. The publishing culture can be very different in different branches. I submitted in the past variations of my results (always different abstract text) with slight updates to several physics conferences, as I knew the audience would be very different. Of course, I myself have the lowest interest to travel to several conferences to show the same results to the same people, would be awkward and non-productive waste of my money and time.

A conference organizer will scrutinize your submission mainly for novelty/plagiarism among the conferences he is organizing (e.g. IEEE conferences) than conferences in related fields. But when your colleague and you are thinking about a conference paper publication based on the same data/graphs/evaluation, then you create a problem for yourselves and the publisher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I understood from your answer is that if the data is not published and only presented then presenting it again at another conference is allowed. But when you send an abstract, the terms you agree to are that the conference has the right to publish the work. This can cause an issue if both conferences decide to publish it for example. Am i correct?

Comment: @MarkBatton Yes, but you should know if you submitted a complete manuscript, digest or just an abstract to the conference. Of course having the same title/abstract without graphs appearing in several conference proceedings or booklets is not ideal for you and the conference organzier, but you won't go to jail for it. But publishing a full manuscript with nearly identical/format results at both conferences is unethical and might get you in problems depending on conference/journal standards. Then one of you might has to retract his submission

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer of [user48953094](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/140886/75368), this can depend on field.

But beyond that, ask yourself why you want to do this and how valuable it will be to those attending the conference or reading the proceedings.

If the data is proprietary or needs to be protected (human research), then you don't gain much from presenting it multiple places. However, if the data can be made available to others for their own research purposes then there is scientific value in presenting it widely and explaining its significance.

So, is the presentation just a "brag" or is it a "gift" to the community.

And, of course, you need to be honest about provenance and the fact that the data is being presented and discussed in several venues.